# Namenode stops working after hadoop restart

Tags: hadoop

I have a server with Hadoop installed on.

I wanted to change some configuration (about the `mapreduce.map.output.compress`); therefore, I changed the configuration file, and I restarted Hadoop, with:

```
stop-all.sh
start-all.sh
```

After that, I was not able to use it again, becouse it was in Safe Mode:

`The reported blocks is only 0 but the threshold is 0.9990 and the total blocks 11313. Safe mode will be turned off automatically`.

Please, notice that the number of reported blocks is 0, and it was not increasing at all.

Therefore, I forced it to leave the Safe Mode with:

```
bin/hadoop dfsadmin -safemode leave
```

Now, I get errors like this:

```
2014-03-09 18:16:40,586 [Thread-1] ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient - Failed to close file /tmp/temp-39739076/tmp2073328134/GQL.jar
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: java.io.IOException: File /tmp/temp-39739076/tmp2073328134/GQL.jar could only be replicated to 0 nodes, instead of 1
```

If it helps, my `hdfs-site.xml` is:

```
<configuration>
<property>
        <name>dfs.replication</name>
        <value>1</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>dfs.name.dir</name>
    <value>/home/hduser/hadoop/name/data</value>
</property>


</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've run into this problem many times. Whenever you get the error stating `x could only be replicated to 0 nodes, instead of 1`, the following steps should fix the problem:

```
Stop all Hadoop services with: stop-all.sh
Delete the dfs/name and dfs/data directories
Format the NameNode with: hadoop namenode -format
Start Hadoop again with: start-all.sh
```

Comment: Sorry, actually that is what I did. I pasted a wrong command. I'm sorry.

Comment: Updated my answer. You actually will need to format your NameNode.

Comment: Ok, many thanks. Am I going to lose all my hadoop files by formatting the HDFS? If so, is there an easy way to avoid it?

Comment: Yes you will. You can use `hadoop dfs -copyToLocal ~/* ~/localDir` to copy the contents of HDFS to a local directory and then move it back in after the format with `hadoop dfs -copyFromLocal ~/localDir ~`

Comment: No, unfortunatly it is not working, becouse I am not able to copy any file from the HDFS. I always get: `copyToLocal: null`

Comment: It sounds like you're not using valid paths to HDFS files.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49364/discussion-between-aslan986-and-leonardblunderbuss)